# "Dumb" SSH Proxying

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel

Most of our developers need SSH access to some of our internal Google Cloud infrastructure.  The way that we're currently handling it is by using a bastion host and having users modify their SSH config to include something like the following:

```
Host *
    ProxyCommand ssh -q bastion.hostname.com 'nc %h %p'
```

We're moving away from a bastion host + metadata SSH keys towards using [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access), but we're trying to minimize the disruption to our developers.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to use something like this:

```
Host *
    ProxyCommand gcloud compute ssh --ssh-key-file="${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa" --internal-ip "%h"
```

However, this doesn't work.  When run with verbose settings enabled, it hangs on:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/mrllama/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[SNIP] explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/mrllama/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[SNIP] explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to [INTERNAL_IP] (via proxy).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: proc
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
```

Note that this `gcloud compute ssh` command works on its own and puts the user at a command prompt, but when used as a ProxyCommand it simply hangs.  Is there a way to make SSH skip all authentication routines after running the ProxyCommand and simply return the prompt instead?

Comment: Just drop it, the developers can `gcloud compute ssh` as well as `ssh`.

Comment: Can you clarify what's your goal ? For many users to be able to connect to one (or many ?) VM's inside your GCP infrastructure ?

Comment: The goal is to have `gcloud compute ssh` work as a `ProxyCommand` in SSH's config.  As to what @MichaelHampton mentioned, I don't particularly care for actual SSH stuff, but it gets really weird when our developers need to use `scp` or `git` (which is configured for SSH, not HTTP[S]).

Comment: Do you want to be able to run `git` over the `gcloud compute ssh` too ? Scp alone works great... and is it an absolute necessity in your use case to have just one command to connect to target instance instead of SSHinch to fist one and then to target ?

Comment: Can you use IAP? `ProxyCommand=gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel your-vm-instance-name 22 --listen-on-stdin --project=your-gcp-project --zone=some-gcp-zone  --verbosity=warning`